# Should I use another user than the root when installing NGiNX

Tags: linux, security, nginx, ubuntu-11.04, server-administration

I herd that it would be better to use a sub-user for installing NGiNX. Is it true? I am thinking to use NGiNX to install virtual-host that my clients could use for there website and I don't want them to have to much control over NGiNX...

I am using Ubuntu Linux distro.

Thanks in advance for any help and/or tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you planning to install these applications?  Since you say you're using Ubuntu, then I would assume that you'll be installing apps via either the graphical manager or by `apt-get` or `aptitude`.

If you're using the graphical program manager, then it should prompt you for your password; this performs a `sudo` under the hood.

If you're using either `apt-get` or `aptitude` or something similar, those programs need to be run as root to install.

In both instances above, the installation scripts for the packages will (should) handle any user-related issues that are necessary for the program you're installing to function properly.  For example, when I did an `apt-get install jenkins`, the installation scripts automatically created a `jenkins` user for me, and my Jenkins CI server runs as the `jenkins` user automatically.

Of course, if you're compiling all of these programs by hand, all bets are off and you'll need to figure out how best to do all of this yourself.  Of course, if you're compiling these programs by hand to get them installed, I'd have to question why you're using Ubuntu in the first place; one of the best parts to using a Linux distribution with sane package management capabilities is actually USING said package management! (Note: by this statement, I mean anything Debian-based for sure; and I understand that Red Hat's `yum` provides very similar capabilities, but I haven't used anything RedHat since around 2003.)

Comment: I am using a package manager. I actually install NGiNX with apt-get following the NGiNX instructions. But the book I am reading is recommending me to use a sub-user. That is why I am asking. Also because I am planning to have VHost so that my clients can have there own space to host there website. I am using RackSpace Cloud so by default I am using the root.

Comment: I followed the instruction at the bottom of the page: http://nginx.org/en/download.html and everything works... I am just worried about security.

Comment: If you installed through the package manager, you likely don't have anything to worry about.  You can check which user your nginx server is running as by issuing the command `ps aux | grep nginx` (assuming that `nginx` is the name of the command; it might be `httpd` or something else; I don't use nginx) and inspecting the output.  From my server running apache: `ps aux | grep apache` ==> `www-data 17053  0.0  0.5 217736 11512 ?        S    12:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start`  Thus, my Apache server is running as the `www-data` user.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a process to have any more access than it needs. So yes, you should use a user besides root -- one that has the minimal privileges required to read the files it needs. Typically this involves creating a new nginx (or www or similar) user specifically for the task.

Comment: What types of rights should I use for the user that I will use to install NGiNX?

Comment: Should I do the same for other apps, like: git, make, gcc, php5, cassandra... ?